# conflict between SimpleModal and Bootstrap modal

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, simplemodal, bootstrap-modal, twitter-bootstrap-2

I Have both these plugins included in same page which is causing conflict in-between them.

I removed the Bootstrap.min.js and SimpleModal worked fine.
I removed jquery.simplemodal.js and Bootstrap modal worked fine.
I Tried to invoke bootstrap modal which worked if the jquery.simplemodal.js is included before bootstrap.min.js

I am getting this error on Firebug console if SimpleModal included after Bootstrap

```
i.modal(...).one is not a function **..blah blah..** bootstrap.min.js (line 6)
```

Comment: Why not use only one modal? If your full website is supported by Bootstrap, why not use Bootstrap model itself, as it is good with other components too right?

Comment: I have a place in my application where if I include the Bootstrap files my whole page's UI gets disturbed, So I included SimpleModal for on that place, resulted me to add this modal on this page as well.

Comment: But you are now stuck up with the whole thing na.

Comment: "I have a place in my application where if I include the Bootstrap files my whole page's UI gets disturbed" -- sounds like you need to rework that code...

Answer (score 6):

Use [the `noConflict` feature of Bootstrap's JS plugins](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#js-noconflict), e.g.:

```
<script src="bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script>
  var bsModal = $.fn.modal.noConflict();
</script>
<script src="SimpleModal.js"></script>
```

Comment: Its showing the same error I have mentioned in this question :(

Comment: @vin Are you using Bootstrap v3.2.0?

Comment: Its showing error in v3.3.7 as well. What is the alternate solution?

Answer (score 1):

You can customize the js provided by Bootstrap in here: http://getbootstrap.com/customize/. Untick "Modals" in JavaScript Components section and you should be good to go with SimpleModal without conflicts with Bootstrap modal.

Comment: how can I customize bootstrap only for Modal & CSS classes related to Modal only?

Comment: 1. Click 'Toggle' on Less files section (it will unselect everything)
2. Select 'Modals' in Less files -> JavaScript components
3. Click 'Toggle' on jQuery plugins section (it will unselect everything)
4. Select 'Modals' in jQuery plugins -> linked to components
5. Hit Compile and Download at the bottom of the page

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
<script src="bootstrap.min.js"></script>    
<script>
    $.fn.bsModal = $.fn.modal.noConflict();
</script>
<script src="SimpleModal.js"></script>
```

and then

```
$('#yourdiv').bsModal();
```